# How to remove the final character

Tags: c++, string

The following function will generate a string with `'\x'` in between,

```
string GetHexEncode(string hexstring){
    string swap = "\\x";
    string h = "\\x";
    int si = hexstring.length();
    for (int i=0; i<hexstring.length(); i++)
    {
        if (i%2==0){
            swap+=hexstring.at(i);
        }
        else
        {
            swap+=hexstring.at(i)+h;
        }
    }
    return swap;
}
```

On occasion, the program outputs the following:

```
\x45\x39\xD3\x5B\x4F\xEA\x6F\x3C\xBC\x1B\xA0\xF4\xE7\x41\xE5\x8
\x45\x39\xD3\x5B\x4F\xEA\x6F\x3C\xBC\x1B\xA0\xF4\xE7\x41\xE5\x
```

If this happens, is there any way that I can change the last part into this:

```
\x45\x39\xD3\x5B\x4F\xEA\x6F\x3C\xBC\x1B\xA0\xF4\xE7\x41\xE5
```

Comment: Yeah: fix your logic so it doesn't output the wrong thing ;-) - seriously though, you really need to provide the input that causes the bad output.

Answer (score 2):

Start out with an empty `swap` and append `h` + digits instead of appending an `\x` at the end.

additionally you should pre-allocate enough space in `swap` before starting your result as you know the final length of your result before. This would save reallocations of the string.